# What can I do when a chat room is in gallery mode and no room owners are around?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, chat

I wanted to ask a question in [the Android room on SO chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) just now, but it's currently in gallery mode. That means I can't say anything unless I am granted permission by one of the room owners. Unfortunately, none of the room owners are present to grant me permission!

What should I do? Is there an accepted solution to this problem? Can this be addressed somehow?

Comment: It looks like that's just how they run their channel. They appear to grant write access on a per-user basis.

Comment: Seems like a fair way of running that particular room, considering all the noise it tends to accumulate otherwise...

Comment: I just find it strange that a chat room with the same name as an extremely popular tag used throughout the community is controlled by a mere 6 people.

Comment: Apparently the room was overrun with noise.  Much like the Android tag on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - So instead it's muted so no conversation takes place at all? There's got to be a better solution.

Comment: It's in Gallery mode.  Have you requested access?

Comment: Yes, it's a social problem that's being handled with a technical solution. I agree that's sub-par, but human psychology has only come so far. If you have some better solutions, don't keep them to yourself!

Comment: I don't see you on the "requested access" list.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I have.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - Well it just seems like the answer would be to treat chat rooms the same way we treat questions. Members with a certain amount of reputation have the ability to remove messages and kick users.

Comment: I granted you read/write access.  *[Waits for the Keepers of the Android to come knocking on my door]*

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Thanks!

Comment: @RobertHarvey Did you grant him write access or was it me? Because I have added him to the write permission list too. :)

Comment: @TheUnicornWhisperer: So now he has Double-Secret Write Access™.

Comment: Hah, we've created a chat monster. That means no one can revoke his write access anymore. :P

Answer (score 4):

We've had quite a lot of troubles in the past to keep the room troll free and the overall quality at a certain level.

I agree that it is not an ideal solution and that the system was never meant to be used like that but that is the only way to have a room where like-minded people can have a proper conversation without millions of *hai-gief-me-teh-codez-plox* messages flying around.

Comment: Yeah, we have the same problem with the [android] tag on Stack Overflow.  Guess that $100 barrier to entry that Apple erects has some purpose after all.

Comment: Wow, they can't even misspell "plz" correctly?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yea, I kinda understand that too now.