# Clean up [stackoverflow] on meta

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

As we all know, the One True Meta is in the works. Of course, there will be a bit of a scuffle on which post goes where, MSO or MSE. Now I don't know how this shall be implemented, but I have a suspicion that it will relate to [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow).

Unfortunately, a lot of questions get this tag just because the OP was using SO at the time, though it relates to the whole site.

To that end, I suggest we sift through [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) and weed out all the questions which apply to all the sites in general.

---

Sifting through the questions I've answered on the tag(most of which are bound to be SE and not SO related since I'm not active on SO), I find some good examples:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129611/where-to-go-if-nobody-answers-your-query/

[Making my own SE-ish site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130211/making-my-own-se-ish-site/)

[iPad Stackoverflow user interface problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130179/ipad-stackoverflow-user-interface-problem/)

And some more, sifting through the tag:

[What can I do when a chat room is in gallery mode and no room owners are around?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130238/what-can-i-do-when-a-chat-room-is-in-gallery-mode-and-no-room-owners-are-around)

---

What say?

Comment: *"though it'"*... missing part?

Comment: @minitech ahh, thanks. Page kept getting refreshed on ipad when I was fetching links, so it got gobbled by that (draft mustve not been saved)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, someone should retag these. In general, it should probably break down as follows:

- Stack Overflow-specific questions should get the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag.
- Global Stack Exchange questions should get the [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) tag.

It's already been discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange). In particular, see [Popular Demand's answer dealing with this concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124021/153008).

Comment: Should we just go ahead with the retag, or organize something? We also have to consider the main-page-flooding issue (or can we just disregard it?). Also, do we _really_ have to tag everything else [stackexchange]?

Comment: Generally, if it's not tagged for a specific site, then it applies to all sites(and thus Stack Exchange as a whole). Normally, when it applies to another specific site, we send it to their specific meta. Really with the creation of MSE, the site-specific tags *should* disappear, no?

Comment: @animuson the issue is, there are questions tagged [stackoverflow] which apply to the whole site. They are tagged as such since the OP doesn't understand MSO--and has noticed the problem/etc on SO. Also, this is a _preparation_ for MSE.

Comment: @animuson see this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130211/making-my-own-se-ish-site/ . It's tagged BOTH [SO] and [SE] (well, it was. I just retagged it). Clear example of new-to-MSO.

Comment: @Manishearth: I was responding in general about the [meta-tag:stackexchange] tag, which seemed a bit useless (but now I realize you could still ask about the company, or other things not actually about "sites"). Then I expanded on how I don't see how site-specific tags will be at all useful when MSE rolls around.

Comment: @animuson yeah, though the proposal was to use these tags only for  the duration of the site-splitting, and then get rid of them. Though [SE] seems like a lot of work to apply everywhere, I say we just stick to cleaning up [SO] and assume all questions not tagged [SO] ought to go to MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I've noticed that a lot of retag requests are missing this. And other stuff.

We ought to sift through [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) and whatnot as well. Note that not all of the [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) are [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow).

The ones which are done need CVs as well.

Comment: Cleaner to just vote to close most of these since these are mostly done

Comment: @random Right, added.  There are still a bunch of open, yet finished ones, eg [all of these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request+status-completed). Should I add a separate meta question for garnering CVs?

Comment: You can add yourself and 10ks will see, or just throw down the link to the search results in meta chat

Comment: @random it's not just _that_ link. I'll do a bit of research and post it, there are some of them, like [tag-synonym], which contain feature requests as well.  And some other cleanup tags I've seen before.

Comment: @random: Could you reply here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131480/help-us-close-completed-retag-requests-and-the-like#comment362570_131480 ?